# Java - How do I add 14 seperate action listeners to each of my Jbuttons outside the inner class?

Tags: java

I'm creating a game called Togiz Kumalak in java. I've had a few problems so far and this one is stumping me.

After adding action listeners to my buttons I started getting the error

**1 error found:
File: C:\Users\Public\Togiz_Kumalak.java  [line: 6]
Error: Togiz_Kumalak is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener**

Before that I simply  had one action listener on the outside of my inner class and it worked fine, but I need separate listeners for each button to determine player turn, and which cup to take seeds(numbers out of)

I can't seem to find a way to add separate action listeners to my buttons outside of the inner class. Any ideas?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Togiz_Kumalak implements ActionListener {








// Window Setup  
private JTextArea display = new JTextArea("Test");
private JPanel window = new JPanel();
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Togiz Kumalak");
private JButton button1 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button2 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button3 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button4 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button5 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button6 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button7 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button8 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button9 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button10 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button11 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button12 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button13 = new JButton("10");
private JButton button14 = new JButton("10");

private JLabel p1Cup = new JLabel("0");
private JLabel p2Cup = new JLabel("0");
private JLabel p1 = new JLabel("Player 1");
private JLabel p2 = new JLabel("Player 2");

private JPanel p1Frame = new JPanel();
private JPanel p2Frame = new JPanel();






//Menu Code





















public Togiz_Kumalak(){

/*Create Window*/
frame.setSize(500,500);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,9));
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));
p1Frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));
p2Frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));

p1Frame.add(p1);
p1Frame.add(p1Cup);
p2Frame.add(p2);
p2Frame.add(p2Cup);






display.setText("TEST");
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(display,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVisible(true);


frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.add(window);
window.add(button1);
window.add(button2);
window.add(button3);
window.add(button4);
window.add(button5);
window.add(button6);
window.add(button7);
window.add(p1Frame);
window.add(button8);
window.add(button9);
window.add(button10);
window.add(button11);
window.add(button12);
window.add(button13);
window.add(button14);
window.add(p2Frame);



/*Add The Action Listener To The Buttons*/
button1.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
button4.setEnabled(false);
button5.setEnabled(false);
button6.setEnabled(false);
button7.setEnabled(false);
button8.setEnabled(true);
button9.setEnabled(true);
button10.setEnabled(true);
button11.setEnabled(true);
button12.setEnabled(true);
button13.setEnabled(true);
button14.setEnabled(true);
    }
  }
);





button2.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
button4.setEnabled(false);
button5.setEnabled(false);
button6.setEnabled(false);
button7.setEnabled(false);
button8.setEnabled(true);
button9.setEnabled(true);
button10.setEnabled(true);
button11.setEnabled(true);
button12.setEnabled(true);
button13.setEnabled(true);
button14.setEnabled(true);
    }

  }
);

button3.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
button4.setEnabled(false);
button5.setEnabled(false);
button6.setEnabled(false);
button7.setEnabled(false);
button8.setEnabled(true);
button9.setEnabled(true);
button10.setEnabled(true);
button11.setEnabled(true);
button12.setEnabled(true);
button13.setEnabled(true);
button14.setEnabled(true);
    }

  }
);


button4.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
button4.setEnabled(false);
button5.setEnabled(false);
button6.setEnabled(false);
button7.setEnabled(false);
button8.setEnabled(true);
button9.setEnabled(true);
button10.setEnabled(true);
button11.setEnabled(true);
button12.setEnabled(true);
button13.setEnabled(true);
button14.setEnabled(true);
    }

  }
);

button5.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
button4.setEnabled(false);
button5.setEnabled(false);
button6.setEnabled(false);
button7.setEnabled(false);
button8.setEnabled(true);
button9.setEnabled(true);
button10.setEnabled(true);
button11.setEnabled(true);
button12.setEnabled(true);
button13.setEnabled(true);
button14.setEnabled(true);
    }
  }
);




button6.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
button4.setEnabled(false);
button5.setEnabled(false);
button6.setEnabled(false);
button7.setEnabled(false);
button8.setEnabled(true);
button9.setEnabled(true);
button10.setEnabled(true);
button11.setEnabled(true);
button12.setEnabled(true);
button13.setEnabled(true);
button14.setEnabled(true);
    }

  }
);




button7.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
button4.setEnabled(false);
button5.setEnabled(false);
button6.setEnabled(false);
button7.setEnabled(false);
button8.setEnabled(true);
button9.setEnabled(true);
button10.setEnabled(true);
button11.setEnabled(true);
button12.setEnabled(true);
button13.setEnabled(true);
button14.setEnabled(true);
    }

  }
);




button8.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
button4.setEnabled(true);
button5.setEnabled(true);
button6.setEnabled(true);
button7.setEnabled(true);
button8.setEnabled(false);
button9.setEnabled(false);
button10.setEnabled(false);
button11.setEnabled(false);
button12.setEnabled(false);
button13.setEnabled(false);
button14.setEnabled(false);
    }

  }
);




button9.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
button4.setEnabled(true);
button5.setEnabled(true);
button6.setEnabled(true);
button7.setEnabled(true);
button8.setEnabled(false);
button9.setEnabled(false);
button10.setEnabled(false);
button11.setEnabled(false);
button12.setEnabled(false);
button13.setEnabled(false);
button14.setEnabled(false);
    }

  }
);





button10.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
button4.setEnabled(true);
button5.setEnabled(true);
button6.setEnabled(true);
button7.setEnabled(true);
button8.setEnabled(false);
button9.setEnabled(false);
button10.setEnabled(false);
button11.setEnabled(false);
button12.setEnabled(false);
button13.setEnabled(false);
button14.setEnabled(false);
    }


  }
);




button11.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
button4.setEnabled(true);
button5.setEnabled(true);
button6.setEnabled(true);
button7.setEnabled(true);
button8.setEnabled(false);
button9.setEnabled(false);
button10.setEnabled(false);
button11.setEnabled(false);
button12.setEnabled(false);
button13.setEnabled(false);
button14.setEnabled(false);
    }

  }
);





button12.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
button4.setEnabled(true);
button5.setEnabled(true);
button6.setEnabled(true);
button7.setEnabled(true);
button8.setEnabled(false);
button9.setEnabled(false);
button10.setEnabled(false);
button11.setEnabled(false);
button12.setEnabled(false);
button13.setEnabled(false);
button14.setEnabled(false);
    }

  }
);





button13.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
button4.setEnabled(true);
button5.setEnabled(true);
button6.setEnabled(true);
button7.setEnabled(true);
button8.setEnabled(false);
button9.setEnabled(false);
button10.setEnabled(false);
button11.setEnabled(false);
button12.setEnabled(false);
button13.setEnabled(false);
button14.setEnabled(false);
    }



  }
);



button14.addActionListener(
new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
button4.setEnabled(true);
button5.setEnabled(true);
button6.setEnabled(true);
button7.setEnabled(true);
button8.setEnabled(false);
button9.setEnabled(false);
button10.setEnabled(false);
button11.setEnabled(false);
button12.setEnabled(false);
button13.setEnabled(false);
button14.setEnabled(false);
    }


  }
);

















// Gameplay hard coded
































/*Make The Window Visible*/
window.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
}





public static void main(String[] args){
new Togiz_Kumalak();
}
}
```

Comment: You're getting this error because you've `implemented ActionListener`, but not implemented the requirements of the contract that it describes.  I'm still not sure what it is you want to do.

Comment: isnt it better to put your Buttons into an array?!

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe the fix was that simple. I removed the implements action listener and it worked.